# How could I search pattern of one file in to another and save the result of each pattern in new file

Tags: grep

I would like to search the patterns of file1 in file2 and the save the result of each pattern in new file. I know how to do do it wiht all the pattern to be search in file 2 and save the results with following:

```
grep -wFf file1 file 2 > outputfile
```

But the problem is I would like to make a seprate output file for each pattern.

How can I do it?

Comment: didn't work. it generates the same number of files as the patterns in file one. But could not do grep. as each output file has exactly the same  containing all the entries of file 2

Comment: patline is supposed to file1 that contains the pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `grep` utility doesn't let you do this out of the box, so in this case you will have to resort to a loop.

Something on the lines of this will do the trick:

```
i=0
while read -r pattern; do
    outfile="data-$(( i++ )).out"
    fgrep -w "$pattern" data.in >$outfile
    if [ ! -s $outfile ]; then
        rm $outfile
    fi
done <patterns.in
```

This also removes any empty files (of patterns that didn't match).

Comment: I tried as you suggested and found this  error                                      'bash: syntax error near unexpected token `do''

Comment: @TCFPHCDG In that case you've probably mistyped something.

Comment: @TCFPHCDG I can reproduce it if I, for example, change the `where` to `if` (which is wrong).

Comment: Is it starts with "for i=0" instead of "i=0"?

Comment: @ TCFPHCDG  It should be exactly like I wrote it in the answer. Nothing added, nothing removed.

Comment: `i=0` creates a variable `i` and initializes it to zero. That variable is later used to create the output file name (incrementing it at the same time). There's no `for`-loop.

Comment: Yes, it worked. Is it possible to name the output file based on pattern. instead of data as you wrote in cod

Comment: @TCFPHCDG Yes, but that might result in very strange or long file names, depending on the contents of `patterns.in`. I would not recommend it. Another solution would be to create a "report" in one single file with the matches annotated with the patterns. Please start a new question about this as this is a separate issue.

Comment: From my pattern.in, it contains the maximum 10 character for each pattern. So it would not be so long.

Comment: Well ok. The quick and dirty way of doing it would simply be to set `outfile="${pattern}.out"`, but that would not sanitize the pattern at all.

Comment: Actually, just ask a new question. A question about creating a report for the matches would not be a bad question. But think about how you would solve it yourself first!